# How to ignore NaN in the dataframe for Mann-whitney u test?

Tags: python, pandas, static, scipy, nan

I have a dataframe as below.

[image]

I want p-value of Mann-whitney u test by comparing each column.
As an example, I tried below.

```
from scipy.stats import mannwhitneyu
mannwhitneyu(df['A'], df['B'])
```

This results in the following values.

> ```
> MannwhitneyuResult(statistic=3.5, pvalue=1.8224273379076809e-05)
> ```

I wondered whether `NaN` affected the result, thus I made the following `df2` and `df3` dataframes as described in the figure and tried below.

```
mannwhitneyu(df2, df3)
```

This resulted in

> ```
> MannwhitneyuResult(statistic=3.5, pvalue=0.00025322465545184154)
> ```

So I think `NaN` values affected the result.
Does anyone know how to ignore `NaN` values in the dataframe?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `df.dropna()` you can find extensive documentation here [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

As per your example, the syntax would go something like this:

```
mannwhitneyu(df['A'].dropna(),df['B'])
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, there is no argument in the `mannwhitneyu` function allowing you to specify its behavior when it encounters `NaN` values, but if you inspect its [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.1.0/scipy/stats/stats.py#L4836-L4925), you can see that it doesn't take `NaN` values into account when calculating some of the key values (`n1`, `n2`, `ranked`, etc.). This makes me suspicious of any results that you'd get when some of the input values are missing. If you don't feel like implementing the function yourself with `NaN`-ignoring capabilities, probably the best thing to do is to either create new arrays without missing values as you've done, or use `df['A'].dropna()` as suggested in the other answer.